# Ruby SSH disable paging

Tags: ruby, ssh, net-ssh

Is there any way to disable or set the page-length of a ruby Net-SSH connection so we don't have to change the settings on the remote device?

In Cisco routers we would use the parameters "terminal length 0" to accomplish this but on other servers we can't use any simular commands. Can this be set via the Net-SSH lib?

Comment: A possible workaround would be `export PAGER=cat`.

Comment: @Jordan I tried this but it didn't work. I've added the line in my .bashrc

Comment: can you paste how you are using net-ssh?

Comment: I personally don't believe you will be able to do this, as paging usually occurs on the server side. Another option would be to use something like [PTY](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html) and [expect](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pty/rdoc/IO.html) to handle the pager.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the remote end has a shell then the terminal height is set in the LINES environment variable.  You can try setting it like this:

```
Net::SSH.start('hostname', 'user') do |ssh|
  ssh.exec!('LINES=50 your-command-here')
end
```

If you don't have a shell you can try having net-ssh push it:

```
ENV['LINES'] = '50'
Net::SSH.start('hostname', 'user', send_env: ['LINES']) do |ssh|
  ssh.exec!('your-command-here')
end
```

However, this requires the cooperation of sshd.  If it's OpenSSH, edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and make sure AcceptEnv includes LINES.